# Wordpress functions.php won't save using unset() PHP function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, unset

I have the unset function in my functions.php theme file and WordPress no longer allows me to save my code in the editor.

I'm using it to unset product tabs on WooCommerce as per this code (found on the WooCoomerce site - https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/editing-product-data-tabs/):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'custom_remove_product_tabs', 98 );
function custom_remove_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    unset( $tabs['description'] ); // Remove the description tab
    return $tabs;
}
```

With this code in I get the generic error of: "Something went wrong. Your change may not have been saved. Please try again. There is also a chance that you may need to manually fix and upload the file over FTP." when saving my functions.php file. If I comment out the line with the unset function is saves just fine.

It does work on the site if I save this code using FTP etc so I appreciate some may say just do that, but I like to quickly edit things inside WordPress sometimes which is no longer possible so want to understand why it's happening (and WordPress have docs on using this function themselves so it's driving me mad!). I've tried adding a standard php unset function with a generic variable to check it's not WooCommerce related but this doesn't work either.

Am I missing something? If not, is it a server setting? We're using PHP 7.4 on a litespeed server so should be up to date. I'm not sure if there is a way to see a more detailed error log from this issue so if there is any help finding it would be great.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So just to be clear, are you saying that once you remove this one single line, saving the whole file works as expected again?

Comment: Hi - yep sorry should have said that. Remove the unset above and the file saves fine.

Comment: Does it work for other tabs? by making use of `unset( $tabs['reviews'] );` or `unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );`

Comment: Your code works without any issue on last Woocommerce version (and last WP version), so there is something else that is making trouble… It can be related to your theme, a plugin or some customizations made by you.

Comment: No same result for any of the tabs. Good idea, OK I'll do some plugin switching on/off and see if I can narrow it down to one of those. Thanks for the suggestions so far sounds like it's definitely something in our setup!